# setState not updating style in react native

Tags: react-native, state

First of all I am very new in react native, and trying to learn it myself and playing around it.

I have a variable name mbackgroundColor. I initialize it in constructor with default value.

```
constructor(props) {
super(props)
this.state = {
    mbackgroundColor: 'green'
};}
```

I have a button within JSX and when I click on it i show a alert successfully.

```
<View style={
[{
height: 50,
}, {backgroundColor : this.state.mbackgroundColor}]
}>
<Button onPress={this.onPressLearnMore}
  title="Learn More"
  color="#841584"
  accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
/>
```

Now When I click on button I also want to setState of bbackgroundColor to white and ***update View also***. ***This is what not happening***.

```
onPressLearnMore() {
Alert.alert('on Press!');
this.setState = {
  mbackgroundColor: 'white'
  };}
```

**I have attached code** [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/195f6eiLt4f89Uo50D2gxWvGf3qXjBbW8/view?usp=sharing).

Thanks for help :)!

Comment: setState is a function. You are attempting to assign to it. You need to pass the object and call the function.

Comment: you should bind context to your `onPressLearnMore` function: `<Button onPress={this.onPressLearnMore.bind(this)}`

Comment: @alok you are facing this context issue. always use arrow function which resolve this context issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` inside the `onPressLearnMore` doesn't refer to the current class, which will throw an error, to get this working change your code to the following.

```
onPressLearnMore = () => {

  Alert.alert('on Press!');

  this.setState({
    mbackgroundColor: 'white',
  });

}
```

to change the value is state, we use this format `this.setState({})` instead of `this.state = {}`

[.setState() tutorial](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/get-pro-with-react-setstate-in-10-minutes-d38251d1c781)

[snack example](https://snack.expo.io/@lekgwaraj/bold-cashew)

And you don't even need the constructor

**change**

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    mbackgroundColor: 'green'
  };
}
```

**to**

```
export default class App extends Component<Props> {

  state = {
    mbackgroundColor: 'green',
  };

  onPressLearnMore = () => {

    Alert.alert('on Press!');
    this.setState({
      mbackgroundColor: 'white',
    });

  };
  ....
```

Comment: obviously you are a good developer, but more a teacher. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Change Your code

**From**

```
onPressLearnMore() {
Alert.alert('on Press!');
this.setState = {
  mbackgroundColor: 'white'
  };}
```

**To**

```
onPressLearnMore() {
this.setState({mbackgroundColor: 'white'},()=>Alert.alert('on Press!')) 
}
```

Comment: thanks!
I have to do two changes:
onPressLearnMore() {
this.setState({mbackgroundColor: 'white'},()=>Alert.alert('on Press!')) 
}


and

{this.onPressLearnMore.bind(this)}

Comment: this will not work, as `this` was not bind to the function.

Comment: @Alok instead of binding, you can use onPress={()=>this.onPressLearnMore}

Answer (score 1):

Just set state like this:

```
this.setState({mbackgroundColor: 'white'})
```

instead of using:

```
this.setState = {
  mbackgroundColor: 'white'
  }
```

Comment: thanks! I have to do two changes: onPressLearnMore() { this.setState({mbackgroundColor: 'white'},()=>Alert.alert('on Press!')) } and {this.onPressLearnMore.bind(this)}